# How to use max command or similar "inside" while command in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, max

```
def main():

    line = input("How many numbers are included? \n")

    numbers_included = int(line)

    i = 0

    sum = 0
    print("Each number should be placed on separate row")
    while i < numbers_included:
        line = input ("")
        number = int(line)
        sum = sum + number
        i = i + 1
    average = sum / numbers_included
    print("Average is",average)
    print("and the biggest digit is", max(number))

main()
```

How can I print greatest number to the code above?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `max`, you need to collect an iterable of numbers to pass into `max()`:

```
...
numbers = [] # here
...
while i < numbers_included:
    line = input ("")
    number = int(line)
    numbers.append(number) # here
    ...
average = sum / numbers_included
print("Average is", average)
print("and the biggest digit is", max(numbers))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Using `for` loop is best without using a `while` loop in this case. And append numbers to a list and use `sum()` and `max()` list operations to do your job.

```
def main():

    line = input("How many numbers are included? \n")

    numbers_included = int(line)
    val_sum = 0
    numbers = []
    print("Each number should be placed on separate row")

    for _ in range(numbers_included):
        line = int(input ())
        numbers.append(line)

    val_sum = sum(numbers)
    average = val_sum / numbers_included
    print("Average is",average)
    print("and the biggest digit is", max(numbers))

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, for fun and concise

```
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        n_lines_str = input("How many numbers are included? \n")
        n_lines = int(n_lines_str )
        print("Each number should be placed on separate row")

        numbers = [int(input()) for i in range(n_lines)]
        mean = sum(numbers) / len(numbers)

        print("Average is {}".format(mean))
        print("Maximum is {}".format(max(numbers)))
```

Comment: There's no need to call `len`; you already know how many numbers there are (`n_lines`).

Comment: Sure, you know they should be equal. The len call is constant time, though, and it means that the mean is actually a mean of what is in the list. Otherwise, we know it is a mean provided that len == n_... But that is one logical level of indirection.